# Set MaxHeight of textblock embedded within data template of ListBox

Tags: c#, datatemplate, silverlight-2.0

how do i access a textblock inside a data template, within a ListBox & set the textblock's 'MaxHeight'?

Code-behind as well?

I have @ Page.xaml:

```
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="" x:Name="NewsList" SelectionChanged="NewsList_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" Width="580" Height="360" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>                                       
                                                <!-- table within each ListBox item-->
                                                <!-- control horizontal scrollbar w width @ following line-->
                                                <Grid Height="110" Width="540">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="82"  />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                            

                                                    <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Gray" Height="82" Width="82" Background="LemonChiffon" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" >                                                
                                                        <Image Source="{Binding NewsThumbnail}" Style="{StaticResource ThumbNailPreview}" />
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="NewsTitle" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="bold"  TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding Title}"  Style="{StaticResource TitleText}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>                                         

<!-- i wish to set the 'maxheight' of the following textblock instead of a fixed value of 65 -->                                                   
<TextBlock x:Name="StaffNewsBody" FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding NewsBody}" Style="{StaticResource DescriptionBlock}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MaxHeight="65" />
```

@ Page.xaml.cs:

```
//variable values taken from App.xaml.cs's method 'Application_Startup()'
public Page(string _setArticles, string _setLength)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_setLength))
    {
        // if (_setLength.Contains("_3"))

      //  if (_setLength.Contains("_4"))

       // if (_setLength.Contains("_5"))
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tutorials on the internet about how to access a control inside data template. You can google it you will find pages like [this](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/getting-the-control-inside-a-datatemplate/) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fb16c929-7318-41de-9ef4-fb62cb1bb45f/). Once you have located the control you want, you can play with it in any way you want and you can apply any change like Maximum Height

**Update:**
See [this](http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/07/how-to-access-a-wpf-control-which-is-located-in-a-datatemplate/), it is the simplest possible way to access a control inside DataTemplate

Comment: Thank you :) is there a simpler examples you know of? They are similar to what i came across for the past 3 days. Please direct me?

Comment: Much appreciated! :) will try it out.

Comment: Ok wow! Its a temporary solution for me but until then, I have 1 less issue. Until then, Thanks again!!