# edit textblock's maxheight when it's embedded within a datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, sharepoint-2007, silverlight-2.0

how do i pass in a 2nd parameter to a Silverlight application (Application_Startup()), edit a textblock's attribute 'MaxHeight' (textblock is embedded within a datatemplate)? Users set the maxheight via the Silverlight control's properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass multiple parameters by using Silverlight's initparams. you have to use a comma as delimiter

```
<param name="initParams" value="favColor=Blue,callbackUrl=http://abc.def.com/mycallback.svc"/>
```

Thorsten

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea how to get about this, as i have an silverlight 2.0 application & a Sharepoint web part project. The difficulty is in accessing the textblock from within the datatemplate i guess?

Comment: Just give your silverlight host (div) and unique identifier or css class and set the initparam by using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your MaxHeight value is available on the web page (in HTML or Javascript) there are many ways to interact with the HTML / DOM from Silverlight plugin... you could use the ScriptObjects... http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics.aspx.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks again. Not what i am looking for but i appreciate it :) You see, for instance, a user selects "3 lines" from a dropdownlist @ a sharepoint web part property, the value gets passed into the silverlight control, & it will display 3 lines worth of information within a textblock embedded within a listbox. Hard to achieve i guess?

Comment: Nope not hard at all. Assuming that your silverlight plugin is on the same sharepoint web page where your combobox is placed, you can use the java script that will fire upon selection of combobox items and send that information to the silverlight object. For this you must study Silverlight's Page Register call for Javascript and [ScriptableMember] attribute... see this ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/04/13/combining-silverlight-2-and-javascript.aspx

Comment: @ user164184: I did look up the link you provided but i do not understand how it may relate to my project. Hmmm, perhaps you can take a look @ this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881863/set-maxheight-of-textblock-embedded-within-data-template-of-listbox

Comment: @mike, can you tell me is this about getting a value from sharepoint web controls to silverlight plugin OR sending a value from a Page to a data template?

Comment: @ user164184: Thanks alot! the latter applies. Solved it already. The approach is lame but still it works :)